# Copying a file and uploading to another csv file with Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, copy-paste

How can I copy all the contents of a csv file and then paste all of it into another csv file and in pandas? The function will delete all the contents in `file2` if there are any and then copy and paste all the contents of `file1` from `file2`. So the content within `file1` should appear on `file2`.

```
file1 =pd.read_csv(`file1.csv`, low_memory=False)
file2 =pd.read_csv(`file2.csv`, low_memory=False)
```

file1 content

```
Hello how are you?
I am good.
What about you.
```

Comment: Why must oyu use pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `to_csv()` method in `pandas`:-

```
file1.to_csv('file2.csv',index=False)
```

You can also do this by file handling:-

```
with open('file1.csv','r') as file1:
    with open('file2.csv','w') as file2:
        file2.write(file1.read())
```

Comment: Generally, I would say it is safer to use `for line in file1: file2.write(line)`. It may be a little slower, potentially, almost certainly it is vastly better memorywise